# Tkinter: Calling function when button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

def load(event):
    file = open(textField.GetValue())
    txt.SetValue(file.read())
    file.close()

def save(event):
    file = open(textField.GetValue(), 'w')
    file.write(txt.GetValue())
    file.close()


win = tk.Tk() 
win.title('Text Editor')
win.geometry('500x500') 

# create text field
textField = tk.Entry(win, width = 50)
textField.pack(fill = tk.NONE, side = tk.TOP)

# create button to open file
openBtn = tk.Button(win, text = 'Open', command = load())
openBtn.pack(expand = tk.FALSE, fill = tk.X, side = tk.TOP)

# create button to save file
saveBtn = tk.Button(win, text = 'Save', command = save())
saveBtn.pack(expand = tk.FALSE, fill = tk.X, side = tk.TOP)
```

I get the error that `load and save are missing a position argument: event`. I understand the error, but don't understand how to resolve it.

Comment: When you create the `tk.Button`s, you're _calling_ the functions because you have, for example, `command = load()` instead of `command = load` in the calling sequence to the constructor.

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, your code shares the same problem as the code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: @martineau I did that. Now its saying the Entry object does not have attribute GetValue. What is the purpose of having event as a parameter in a function anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a runnable answer. In addition to changing the `commmand=` keyword argument so it doesn't call the function when the `tk.Button`s are created, I also removed the `event` argument from the corresponding function definitions since `tkinter` doesn't pass any arguments to widget command functions (and your function don't need it, anyway).

You seem to be confusing event handlers with widget command function handlers. The former *do* have an `event` argument passed to them when they're called, but the latter typically don't (unless you do additional stuff to make it happen—it's a fairly common thing to need/want to do and is sometimes referred to as the[*The extra arguments trick*](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/extra-args.html)).

```
import tkinter as tk

# added only to define required global variable "txt"
class Txt(object):
    def SetValue(data): pass
    def GetValue(): pass
txt = Txt()
####

def load():
    with open(textField.get()) as file:
        txt.SetValue(file.read())

def save():
    with open(textField.get(), 'w') as file:
        file.write(txt.GetValue())

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Text Editor')
win.geometry('500x500')

# create text field
textField = tk.Entry(win, width=50)
textField.pack(fill=tk.NONE, side=tk.TOP)

# create button to open file
openBtn = tk.Button(win, text='Open', command=load)
openBtn.pack(expand=tk.FALSE, fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)

# create button to save file
saveBtn = tk.Button(win, text='Save', command=save)
saveBtn.pack(expand=tk.FALSE, fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'event' arguments from both function defs and remove brackets from your commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use button.bind() mehtod and pass 'Button-1' in first argument and function name in second argument
def functionname(event):
  #your code

```
button = tk.Button(win, text="Login", bg="green")#, command=attempt_log_in)
button.grid(row=5, column=2)
button.bind('<Button-1>', functionname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have functions **save** and **load** that takes 1 argument : **event** but when you called

```
# create button to open file
openBtn = tk.Button(win, text = 'Open', command = **load()**) <<<--- no argument in load
                                                       <<<---should be load(someEvent)
openBtn.pack(expand = tk.FALSE, fill = tk.X, side = tk.TOP)
# create button to save file
saveBtn = tk.Button(win, text = 'Save', command = **save()**)<<< ---- same for the save
saveBtn.pack(expand = tk.FALSE, fill = tk.X, side = tk.TOP)
```

But in your function **save** and **load** the argument : **event** you don't do nothing with it so you can just **delete the event argument** and this problem shouldn't appear. Like this :

```
def load():
    file = open(textField.GetValue())
    txt.SetValue(file.read())
    file.close()

def save():
    file = open(textField.GetValue(), 'w')
    file.write(txt.GetValue())
    file.close()
```