# how do I make a button in Tkinter that runs a shell command

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button the command: `print("test")`. Here is what I have so far:

```
import os
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(text="print",
                   fg="black",
                   command=print("test")
                   )
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you actually want to run a _shell_ command? (Or just Python?)

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447065/tkinter-calling-function-when-button-is-pressed), the following should work:

```
import os
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(text="print",
                   fg="black",
                   command=lambda: print("test")
                   )
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```